# What is the difference between mysql when run from the console (eg cmd.exe) and mysqlsh?

Tags: mysql

On Windows I can run

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>mysql -u root -pxxxx
```

or alternatively there is a shell-like program at `"MySQL Shell x.y\bin\mysqlsh.exe"`

What is the difference, in high-level terms, between these two? When would you use one over the other, and why?  I have a lot of experience with sqlplus on Oracle; is the mysqlsh like sqlplus, in the sense that it provides much more functionality than console access that is possible through cmd.exe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be a better suited question for https://superuser.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL Shell is a superset of the functionality of the `mysql` client. It has several features that the old client doesn't have, for example:

- You can write statements in Python or Javascript in addition to SQL statements, so you can write scripts that do any kind of loop or conditional code you can imagine in Python or Javascript.
- You can connect to multiple MySQL sessions concurrently, for example to connect to multiple servers.
- You can output query results in different formats, including JSON.
- You can use the "X Protocol" which allows you to query MySQL like a NoSQL server instead of an SQL server.

MySQL Shell is sort of being presented as a successor to the traditional `mysql` client tool. But it's a relatively new tool and probably has some undiscovered bugs (any new software does).

The old `mysql` tool is not going away. There are too many apps and scripts that make extensive use of that old client tool, and while the new MyQL Shell can do the same tasks, the usage is different, so for backward compatibility, I assume the old tool will exist forever.

For more information, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-features.html